# How to make a textview start at 26% of the screen and go until 96% of the screen?

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I was wondering how I could make a TextView shows up like the pictures shown below:

[small http://raphaeu.com/gvt/img_forum_small.jpg](http://raphaeu.com/gvt/img_forum_small.jpg)
[average http://raphaeu.com/gvt/img_forum_medium.jpg](http://raphaeu.com/gvt/img_forum_medium.jpg)
[big http://raphaeu.com/gvt/img_forum_large.jpg](http://raphaeu.com/gvt/img_forum_large.jpg)

In other words, I need to be able to position a TextView in the following way:

1. The top-left corner of the TextView must be at 38% of the screen (vertical) and 26% of the screen (horizontal).
2. The bottom-right corner of the TextView must be at 100% of the screen (vertical) and 96% of the screen (horizontal).

That way I can guarantee that the TextView layout will be always proportional the way I want, no matter the screen-size of the device.

PS: For all means, I’m considering that the coordinate-system on Android starts at the top-left corner of the screen (0, 0) and the coordinates of bottom-right corner of the screen is (100%, 100%).

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Later edit: Modified to include scrolling.

It's doable, but it gets very ugly quick. Here's what I managed to do (the view you want is the red rectangle):

[image]

I used a `TableLayout` and `layout_weight` attributes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TableRow android:layout_weight="38" />
    <TableRow android:layout_weight="62">
        <TextView android:layout_weight="26" />
        <ScrollView android:layout_weight="70" 
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:background="#ff0000">
            <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
                      android:layout_weight="match_parent" />
        </ScrollView>
        <TextView android:layout_weight="4" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: That worked! I just had to change android:layout_width="match_parent" to android:layout_width="fill_parent"and android:layout_height="match_parent" to android:layout_height="fill_parent" (It shows an error otherwise).

Once you said that this solution "get's very ugly quick" I'm wondering if there is a better way to do it. If there is, please, let me know. At the mean time, I'll stick with this solution.

Thanks a million!!

Comment: I'm glad I could help. I have no idea how it could be implemented in other ways, sorry. If it works, don't fix it, you know :)

Comment: I hadn't tested this code with some text inside the TextView yet. When I put some text inside the TextView, the TextView gets bigger. I don't want that to happen. I want that the TextView stays in the exact same proportion that it already has (without any text).

Comment: Add `android:layout_width="0dp"` to the `TextView` and see if it works.

Comment: That worked. If you could just bare with my one more time... Now I'm facing problems in how to put a ScrollView wrapping around that TextView. I want to be able to scroll the text in case it gets too large, but I'm not succeeding on doing that... I simply cannot put a ScrollView around the TextView (in that exactly same position).

Answer (score 1):

Usually, positioning views in Android is done in XML. Check out this post, it surely will help you: [Declaring Layout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html)

Comment: I have read that link already, but I was not able to do what I'm asking here, which is to position a TextView in terms of percentage of the screen. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with android:layout_weight parameter. If you have 2 views inside LinearLayout and want the first to be 25% and the second 75% you set their weights to 75 and 25 (ie in the reverse order).

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="4">

        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="70" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="26"
            android:text="Text" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="96" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: That works for the horizontal problem I have, but it doesn't fix the vertical one. That's a good solution though, I'll make sure to write it down as well, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you do not mind creating your views programatically, at runtime you can find the size of the screen and then just multiply by whichever constants you need to start the text view at the appropriate spot.

Comment: I had this idea as well, but I'd like to do it directly in the XML file.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `android:padding` or `android:layout_margin` as per
[padding](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setPadding) or [margin](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams.html#setMargins)